# calling prompt() in electron (from external API) does not work

Tags: node.js, ace-editor, electron

I am using the [ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) editor inside of electron. When pressing `ctrl+l` inside the editor `prompt()` is invoked by ace. But Electron does not support `prompt()` so that functionality does not work.

> **[zcbenz commented on Oct 26, 2014:](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/472#issuecomment-60515607)**
>
> There is no native prompt dialogs in most GUI toolkits, so
>   implementing prompt in atom-shell would require writing the prompt
>   dialog from ground up on all platforms. Due to the rare use of prompt,
>   I think it doesn't deserve to do all the work, and it is very easy to
>   use a web implemented solution for this.
>
> So I'm closing this as won't fix.

I have fixed this problem (for) now by extending ace, but if yet another external module calls `prompt()` I will have to do something like this again. The code below binds to `ctrl+l` and then replace `prompt()` by [vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/)(yet another dependency) and then call `gotoLine()`:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "replace",
    bindKey: {
        win: "Ctrl-l",
        mac: "Command-l"
    },
    exec: function(editor) {
        vex.dialog.open({ // ********** prompt() **********
            message: 'Enter your line number:',
            buttons: [
                $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.YES, {
                    text: 'goto line'
                })
            ],
            input: "<input name=\"line\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"line\" required />\n",
            callback: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    editor.gotoLine(data.line)
                    editor.focus()
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Ideally I would just instantiate another module(add just one line) which implements the prompt as a synchronous function that works inside electron. I am wondering if there is already a module for this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you having trouble integrating the ACE api into your electron app? If so, what is the specific problem?

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for taking a look at this question. I tried to improve my question. I hope it can be better understood now, because my question was not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try smalltalk, it's a Promise-based solution for alert, confirm and prompt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/smalltalk